# incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. how can I fix it?

Tags: c, clion

While running the code I am getting the error: ds(57203,0x70000fba3000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff875402848: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Sometimes it works, sometimes it crashes after trying to malloc a new node (see createNode function) so I suspect the error is coming from there.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I've tried debugging the code and changing several mallocs but couldn't fix the problem.

As I told earlier, I suspect the error is in createNode function.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <string.h>


void* threadFunction(void* searchTerm);
void scanDirName(char * path, char * searchTerm);
char* rootSD;
pthread_mutex_t qlock;

struct Node {
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

// Two glboal variables to store address of front and rear nodes.
    struct Node* front = NULL;
    struct Node* rear = NULL;

// To Enqueue an integer
void Enqueue(char* x) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);
/*    printf("\nhere\n");*/
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data =x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = temp;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
}

// To Dequeue an integer.
char* Dequeue() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);
    struct Node* temp = front;
    if(front == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
        return NULL;
    }
    char* data;
    data = front->data;
    if(front == rear) {
        front = rear = NULL;

    }
    else {
        front = front->next;
    }

    free(temp);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
    return data;
}


void Print() {
    struct Node* temp = front;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void* threadFunction(void* st){

    char* filepath;
    filepath = NULL;
    char* searchTerm;
    searchTerm = (char*)st;

    while (filepath == NULL) {
        filepath = Dequeue();
    }

    printf("about to enter with %s, %s\n",filepath, searchTerm);
    fflush(stdout);
    scanDirName(filepath, searchTerm);
    if (strcmp(filepath,rootSD) != 0)
        free(filepath);
    return (void*)1;


}

void scanDirName(char * path, char * searchTerm){
    DIR * d = opendir(path); // open the path
    char* str3;

    if(d==NULL) return; // if was not able return

;

    struct dirent * dir; // for the directory entries
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) // if we were able to read somehting from the directory
    {

        if(dir-> d_type == DT_DIR){ //
            if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 & strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0) // if it is a directory
            {
                str3 = malloc(1+strlen("/") + strlen(searchTerm)+ strlen(dir->d_name) );
                if (!str3){
                    return;
                }

                strcpy(str3, path);
                strcat(str3, "/");
                strcat(str3, dir->d_name);
                printf("\n---\n%s\n---\n",str3);
                Enqueue(str3);
                printf("Succ");
            }
        } else if(dir-> d_type == DT_REG){ //
            if(strstr(dir->d_name, searchTerm)){

                printf("%s/%s\n", path, dir->d_name);
            }
        }

    }
    closedir(d); // finally close the directory
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    if (argc != 4){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* rootSearchDir = argv[1];
    char* searchTerm = argv[2];
    int threadsNumber = atoi(argv[3]);

    pthread_t threadsCollection[threadsNumber];

    rootSD = rootSearchDir;
    Enqueue(rootSearchDir);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<threadsNumber; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&threadsCollection[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void*)searchTerm)) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;

        }
    }

    int rc;

    for (i=0; i<threadsNumber; i++){
        rc = pthread_join((threadsCollection[i]), NULL);
        if(rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread, %d\n", rc);
            return 1;

        }
    }



}

}
```

This code searches for files that their name contains searchTerm starting from root search dir using threads.

Comment: Note: in `isEmpty`: the check `if (pQueue == NULL)` should return `true` as if there is no queue, then at least it is empty.

Comment: Check the `Dequeue` action for when there is only one item in the queue. Note that in `Enqueue`, when the queue is empty, then it sets `pQueue->head = pQueue->tail = item;`

Comment: You never initialize the pointer prev in creating a node, therefore their contents are indeterminate and if you dereference them you’ll get undefined behavior. Might not cause this but is still a problem.

Comment: The error is my previous comment: the item is not dequeued.

Comment: Maintaining a `size` is not the right way: the queue is empty when head & tail are null. Maintaining a size is error prone.

Comment: Hey, @PaulOgilvie thanks for helping! It seems like my queue has lots of problems, I copied a queue implementation from the internet and it seems like I still have the same problem.

Comment: You allocate memory for `seartItem`                 `str3 = malloc(1+strlen("/") + strlen(searchTerm)+ strlen(dir->d_name) );` but copy `path`  `strcpy(str3, path);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are allocating size of `searchTerm` but copying the `path`.

The chances of length of `path` and length of `searchTerm` is same is less. Thus accessing out of bound for `str3` and invoking undefined behavior.

```
         str3 = malloc(1+strlen("/") + strlen(searchTerm)+ strlen(dir->d_name) );
            if (!str3){
                return;
            }

            strcpy(str3, path);  //Here
            strcat(str3, "/");
            strcat(str3, dir->d_name);
```

To solve allocate the memory with length of `path`.

```
str3 = malloc(1+strlen("/") + strlen(path)+ strlen(dir->d_name) );
```